# isolated singularity / Laurent series

Tags: laurent-series, singularity

I want to classify the singularities of $f(z)=\frac{\cos^2 z}{\sin^2 z}$
Maybe I can write: $$f(z)=\frac{\cos^2 z}{\sin^2 z} = \frac{1-\sin^2 z}{\sin^2 z} =  \frac{1}{\sin^2 z}-1.$$
I can substitute $\sin^2 z= \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2z))$. Then $\cos(2z)=1 $ for $ z=k\pi$ How can I go on from there?

Comment: You have all the singularities.  What more do you want?  Note that you could have just use the zeros of sin$z$. which are the same.

Comment: I want to know what kind of singularites are these. I would say: poles of  order 2?

Comment: Near 0 $sin(z)\approx z$, so poles would be of order 2.

Comment: I see:) And the singularities at $k \pi  \ for \ k \ne 0$

Comment: Fo$z=k\pi+z'$, where $z'\approx 0,\ sin^2(z)\approx  z'^2$, so pole of order 2 for ALL $z=k\pi$.

Comment: Moreover what you wrote only holds for $z$ real while you seem to be assuming that $z$ is complex

Answer (score 1):

For $z=kπ+z′$, where $z′≈0$, $sin^2(z)≈z′^2$, so pole of order $2$ for ALL $z=kπ$.